# Does PVC conduit need a termination bushing at a service panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I'm installing a panel with the feed conductors entering via 1-1/2" PVC. Is an end bushing, as shown here (for example), required by the U.S. NEC for PVC?

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.diychatroom.com/f18/metal-lock-nut-pvc-adapter-panel-348714/)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the NEC:

> 352.46 Bushings. Where a conduit enters a box, fitting, or
>   other enclosure, a bushing or adapter shall be provided to
>   protect the wire from abrasion **unless the box, fitting, or
>   enclosure design provides equivalent protection.**

The important part is bolded above - you need a bushing unless your fitting provides equivalent protection - that is, equivalent to the protection a bushing provides.

You'll probably terminate your conduit in your panel with either a PVC male terminal adapter:

[image: male terminal adapter]

or a PVC box adapter:

[image: box adapter]

I think anyone would agree the box adapter provides protection equivalent to a bushing.

I believe it's generally accepted that a PVC male adapter does provide equivalent protection, but you might find someone that disagrees, and some of them are pretty sharp.  I usually ream them with lineman's pliers to take the edge off and do without the bushing.

The box adapters make a great connection but since they are cemented on, they are a pain if you have to remove and replace them.

Answer (score 2):

The Code section (NEC 300.4(G)) about bushing requirements does not state plastic or metal raceway. It just says to install bushings at threaded ends of conduits, with no references to the kind of material the conduit is made from. So, both plastic and metal raceways require them per Code with #4 cable and bigger. Plastic raceway ends are also very sharp to the touch; rub your hand around it and see.

Answer (score 1):

A bushing is typically NOT required when using PVC conduit. However, for the sake of completeness I always use a bushing...

Comment: By completeness I mean I'll do it even if it seems to be or is overkill. This is my personal preference tho.